# AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) automatic Backup

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

------------------- AWS RDS (PostgreSQL DB) Backup -----------------------

Production PostgreSQL Instance:

Backup:      After Every 4 Hours backupscript should be run and take the full backup of DB.
Retation: We want to retail/keep last month backup and delete all backup file older than one month.

UAT PostgreSQL Instance:

Backup:      Backup daily at once a day.
Retation: We wanted to keep/retail the last once week backup and rest the old backup files wanted to delete.

---

How can I set up an automatic backup as per my above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS supports backup Out of the Box, hence you could utilize those. You could setup customized rules for both `production/UAT`.

> Backup--you could do automated at your preferred time or RDS data center default windows.

Refer [Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) documentation for the same.

> Retention--default retention policy is one day, but you could set it up in RDS console as your preferred time. You could setup customized rules for both `production/UAT`.
>
> You could do both backup and retention manually as well , by your own custom export script, and saving the exported data to S3 or glacier or EBS.

Step could be

> Export the data using pg_export.
>
> Put exported file/files to S3 with desired [retention policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/).

Refer S3 [retention](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) policy docs for more details.

Comment: I need to backup the RDS PostgreSQL db not Redshift DB. i read that reference doc of redshift its only for that not PostgreSQL db.

Comment: Remove Redshift from question tag.